# Electron removes top bar when packed

Tags: javascript, electron, atom-editor, electron-packager

I'm building an Electron app, i have developed everything and it works fine, but when i use `electron-packager .` to build my application to an exe the top menú dissapears.

I initialize it using remote, because i do that in the renderization time;

```
const {electron, Menu} = require("electron").remote;
```

Then, i build the menu from a template;

```
  var m = new Menu();
  m = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(m);
```

It works fine when i run the app with `electron .` but when i pack it the top menu dissapears.

Two images to show what i am saying;

[image: Running it with electron .]

[image: And running the packed .exe]

Thanks.

Comment: what electron version? maybe [related](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21268)

Comment: 7.1.12, the shame in the post you shared, but it says can´t remove, i need to maintain it when i pack the app. Thanks